# Logstash grok pattern for space field

Tags: logstash-grok

Hi How to write a grok expression for the below log

```
[2017-03-25T00:00:07,137][WARN ]

match => { "message" => "\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}/]/[%{LOGLEVEL:log-level}\s*\]" }
```

Is this correct , how to write space in grok ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`%{SPACE}` is that pattern that matches 0 or more spaces, which is very useful if you don't know (or care!) if there will be a space or not.

Comment: Thanks! very usefull. Sometimes you don't notice that you have more spaces between log fields....

Comment: try `%{SPACE}*` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56641572/1726026)

Comment: I was searching for the same .. found this works: \s+

Comment: trim every space until next character. Thank you!