# Accommodate uncertain number of Spaces in a log file GROK pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

This may be a simple question, but in my logs the spaces between different fields are uncertain, that mean in some logs I can see two spaces and in some three between the same fields. How do we accommodate this in GROK?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%{SPACE}*` in your grok pattern for matching uncertian number of spaces. It will match even if spaces are present or not.

Answer (score 1):

Grok is at it's heart an overlay on Regex's.  So in your grok pattern, you can directly use Regex syntax:

```
 %{WORD} +%{WORD}
```

So "space+" means one or more spaces.  "space*" means 0 or more spaces.

Grok also has a pattern %{SPACE} that is equivilent to " *"